# What was the Biblical Basis Tertullian used to support what he termed the "refrigerium interim"?

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology, early-church, afterlife, tertullian

The early Christian theologian Tertullian used the term *refrigerium interim* to describe a happy state in which the souls of the blessed are refreshed while they await the Last Judgment and their definitive entry into Heaven [(source).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refrigerium)

***What was the Biblical Basis he used to support this concept?***

Comment: If you are specifically looking for the biblical basis that Tertullian uses for his concept of *refrigerium interim*, then I don't think that would be a duplicate, but as it stands I don't see the difference between this question and the one linked above.

Comment: @Nathaniel, Yes.My question is not a duplicate. I am specifically looking for the biblical basis that Tertullian uses for his concept of refrigerium interim.I am not just asking about an interim state but about a specific kind of an interim state (i.e. the refrigerium interim of Terullian).

Comment: This question would be more interesting than the other one _if_ there was anything unique about it. However I don't see any evidence that "Tertullian's basis" is going to come up with anything different than the general "biblical basis" question which is already scoped by default to anybody who holds the view, and this is likely answered by the same set of verses in the source you linked to.